# MySQL: Selecting an entry's parent and grandparent names

Tags: mysql

On my site, I have several articles, and each article is assigned to a location with a category. This is how it has been set up for quite some time, so I can't change how it works.

The relationship between these is set in two tables, *categories* and *category_posts*:

```
categories

+--------+------------------+------------------+-----------+
| cat_id | cat_name         | cat_url_title    | parent_id |
+--------+------------------+------------------+-----------+
|  1     | Toronto          | toronto          | 2         |
|  2     | Ontario          | ontario          | 3         |
|  3     | Canada           | canada           | 0         |
|  4     | Vancouver        | vancouver        | 5         |
|  5     | British Columbia | british_columbia | 3         |
|  6     | Montreal         | montreal         | 7         |
|  7     | Quebec           | quebec           | 3         |
|  8     | San Francisco    | san_francisco    | 9         |
|  9     | California       | california       | 10        |
|  10    | United States    | united_states    | 0         |
+--------+------------------+------------------+-----------+

category_posts

+----------+--------+
| entry_id | cat_id |
+----------+--------+
| 990      | 1      |
| 991      | 4      |
| 992      | 8      |
| 993      | 6      |
| 994      | 4      |
| 995      | 4      |
| 996      | 1      |
| 997      | 6      |
| 998      | 8      |
| 999      | 4      |
| 1000     | 3      |
| 10001    | 10     |
+----------+--------+
```

So *category posts* contains a list of all the articles' entry id's, and which category they have been assigned. Then the *categories* table lists all the categories, including their parents and their URL titles.

What I'm trying to do is write a query that for any article entry id, returns its category name and url title, as well of those of its parents and grandparents.

So for example, if I used 999 as the entry id, this is the result I would want:

```
+-----------+---------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| cat_name  | cat_url_title | parent_name      | parent_url_title | grandparent_name | grandparent_url_title |
+-----------+---------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
| Vancouver | vancouver     | British Columbia | british_columbia | Canada           | canada                |
+-----------+---------------+------------------+------------------+------------------+-----------------------+
```

Now, I'm kind of stuck with writing a query to do that. I know how to get just the entry's own category name and url title using this query:

```
SELECT cat_name, cat_url_title FROM categories
JOIN category_posts
ON categories.cat_id=category_posts.cat_id
WHERE category_posts.entry_id = 999;
```

But how would I include the parent and grandparent categories? Hopefully that makes sense.

EDIT: I just realized a modification is necessary. I can't be certain that only child categories will be selected as the category for every article. Parent and even grandparent categories could also be selected. When I put the such an article's entry id into the query, it returns with no results. I updated the category_posts table to show this. Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can join three instances of your categories table to get that:

```
SELECT 
child.cat_name as child_cat_name, child.cat_url_title as child_cat_url_title, 
parent.cat_name as parent_cat_name, parent.cat_url_title as parent_cat_url_title, 
grandparent.cat_name as grandparent_cat_name, grandparent.cat_url_title as grandparent_cat_url_title 
FROM categories as child 
JOIN category_posts ON child.cat_id=category_posts.cat_id
JOIN categories as parent on child.parent_id = parent.cat_id
JOIN categories as grandparent on parent.parent_id = grandparent.cat_id
WHERE category_posts.entry_id = 999;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    c1.cat_name,
    c1.cat_url_title,
    c2.cat_name AS parent_name,
    c2.cat_url AS parent_url_title,
    c3.cat_name AS grandparent_name,
    c3.cat_url AS grandparent_url_title
FROM categories c1
INNER JOIN categories c2 ON (c1.parent_id = c2.cat_id)
INNER JOIN categories c3 ON (c2.parent_id = c3.cat_id)
INNER JOIN category_posts p ON (c1.cat_id = p.cat_id)
WHERE p.entry_id = 999;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this :

```
select c.cat_name,c.cat_url_title,
    b.cat_name as cat_name_parent,b.cat_url_title as cat_url_title_parent,
    a.cat_name as cat_name_grandparent,a.cat_url_title as cat_url_title_grandparent
from categories a
inner join categories b on b.parent_id = a.cat_id
inner join categories c on c.parent_id = b.cat_id
inner join category_posts d on c.cat_id = d.cat_id and d.entry_id = '999'
```